# Transferring Files Over Ethernet to Network Storage Kills Internet Connection

Tags: macos, networking, ethernet, storage, osx-yosemite

I have an Airport Extreme router (newest model) with a USB drive attached that I transfer files to.

My Mac Pro (3,1 running latest Yosemite) is connected to this router via Ethernet, and I've been running into a strange issue...sometimes file transfers will totally kill the internet connection.

Specifically, the Finder progress bar will freeze, Finder will hang, and the internet connection dies entirely. Finder then has to be force quit, it won't relaunch, and the internet stays dead until I reboot the machine.

It seems as though this is easier to trigger when there's a lot of data moving around, if I have something downloading in Safari for example. But heavy internet traffic isn't required to cause the system to choke in this way...sometimes all it takes is a single file to be moving from the Mac to the network storage drive, with no other app open, no other machines using the network, and the above phenomenon still occurs.

Network settings are default, configured automatically.

I've been seeing this for a while now (not just on Yosemite either) but haven't found much info that might explain why. It's getting annoying enough that I want to solve it.

Anyone encountered something like this?

Comment: Just for clarification, when you state that the internet dies, do you need to reboot your router or modem?  Which one/both?  Secondly, although it probably doesn't matter, do you know if you have jumbo frames enabled?

Comment: Hi Matthew! I mean I have to reboot the computer, not the router+modem. The internet is fine for other devices, the connection just dies on this Mac. And no, my MTU is the standard 1500 (set automatically).

Comment: Well, since it's hardware or software at this point, next time this happens, could you try the following commands in a terminal to see if it resolves the issue?  "sudo ifconfig [interface name] down" and "sudo ifconfig [interface name] up"?  It would narrow down if it's something NIC related or something in Yosemite that's throwing a fit.

Comment: What does your "All Messages" log stream in Console.app report around the time this happens?

Comment: @Spiff, I'm going to try triggering it again to verify but at around the time it happened yesterday I have hundreds of identical Console entries like this: `2015-04-21 6:16:20.583 PM com.apple.MediaLibraryService[722]: void *NSMapGet(NSMapTable *, const void *): map table argument is NULL`

Comment: @Matthew_Sp I just triggered the error again to test this, and the ifconfig commands did revive the internet without me needing to restart. It also allowed me to stop the stalled Finder transfer without it hanging or crashing, which is nice. [Here's a screenshot](http://d.pr/i/18GKD) of the console during the downtime.